# Finding integer such that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{5}}) =Q(\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{c})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

After some helpful feedback on my first question, I will repost my question with some more additional information.

For a programming project, I need to calculate the L-series to a Groessencharacter. In order to use some built-in SAGE functions for certain Zetafunctions, I have the following problem:
Given a field extension L = $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{5}})$ of K = $\mathbb  Q(\sqrt{5})$. The numbers $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ and furthermore, $d = \sqrt{a+b\sqrt{5}}$ is totally negative in L and is a discriminant of the relative extension L/K.

The question that I have: is there an integer $ c \in \mathbb Z$, such that  L = $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{c})$?

My naive idea so far: If I think about the ideal $(d) = (-10+2\sqrt{5})$ in K, then I can factor this ideal into $(d) = (2)^2(\sqrt{5})$. My guess would that I could cancel one of the (2) ideals, to make it squarefree and that I could (somehow) cancel the $(\sqrt{5})$. This would leave me with $L = K(\sqrt{2})$. I have a feeling, that this calculation could generalize into my question. Is this thinking correct?

I did try to check if a similar question has already been answered but I had only found a lot of question with regards to the Galois  Group of L/$\mathbb Q$. Thanks a lot in advance!